# Updating jTable - passing jTable as a parameter

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdbc, jtable

I have a method in class A and I want class B (Main GUI) to call that method, but class A needs to perform some action on a jTable within class B.

I do not want this method to be within class B as it needs a connection to the db and I don't want my GUI to hold any such methods.

Here is the code within class A:

```
public void populatejTable(TableModel x) {
    try {
        String stmt = "SELECT * FROM APP.DATAVAULT";
        PreparedStatement ps = Main.getPreparedStatement(stmt);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        x.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I need to pass a parameter of type jTable to set it's model. I've tried all different common data types such as String, int etc... and even tried jTable and TableModel.

I'm guessing you're not really supposed to do this, but I cannot see a better way around this?

Here is the code calling this method within class B (my GUI):

```
//table
Account acc = new Account();
acc.populatejTable(datavaultjTable);
```

How should I go about doing this?

I am using Netbeans 7.3 Beta 2 GUI builder to create the table and the GUI - writing in Java on OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in class A doesn't compile. There is no `setModel()` method in TableModel. Your goal of not having database-related code in a GUI class is a good one, but if it leads to GUI code in database-related code, the result is even worse.

The GUI class should contain GUI code only. The data access code should contain database-related code only. The GUI should call methods on the database access code to get data. It should not pass JTable instances or even TableModel instances to the data access code:

```
public class GUI {
    private JTable table;
    private MyTableModel tableModel;
    private DataAccess dataAccess;
    ...

    public void fillTableWithDataFromDatabase() {
        List<Product> products = dataAccess.getProductsFromDatabase();
        tableModel.setProducts(products);
    }
}

public class DataAccess {
    public List<Product> getProductsFromDatabase() {
        // TODO:
        // create an empty list
        // execute a query
        // loop through each row
        // for each row, create a Product instance and add it to a list
        // return the list
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, I guess I should not be doing this at all. The code will not compile for you as I am using a .jar I found online for populating jTables made from a GUI builder. Back to the drawing board! Thank you very much for the code example, I'll get cracking.

Comment: Should this not be private TableModel not MyTableModel? I don't want to edit just incase I'm missing something here but I'm 99% sure..

Comment: TableModel is an interface. You must use an implementation of this interface. MyTableModel would be such an implementation (extending AbstractTableModel, for example), that would display instances of `Product`, and have a `setProducts()` method that would replace the products being displayed by your table.